# How to reuse the same google map street view object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map and some markers, on clicking the markers I want to open up a street view map, which can be closed and open up again.

I have tried using single global street view instance and using display:none to hide it, problem is, the map won't show render again after it has been hidden.

I also tried initiating new global instance every time, but looks like old instances are not destroyed, and renders new overlays on top of older overlays.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Edit:

Probably a separate question, if above is not easy to achieve, how do I switch existing map to street view mode, given a lat lng? I have been searching on google and couldn't find any apparent result.

Comment: If you vote my question down, please provide your reason.

Comment: Did you try setVisible(false)?

Comment: @bfavaretto I believe it won't work because the street view div sits inside the popup div, I will need to hide the popup div, and ultimately the street view div will be affected by `display:none`

Comment: And are you sure display:none is the cause? Anyway, considering your update: map.getStreetView()

Comment: @bfavaretto yeah thanks, just read the pagehttps://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas carefully again and found it.

Comment: You have to set it to visible https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, just saw it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was wrong about "I also tried initiating new global instance every time, but looks like old instances are not destroyed, and renders new overlays on top of older overlays." So it is workable.

And regarding to my question update, I got my answer from the following link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

Here is the code in case you have similar purpose:

```
var sv = map.getStreetView();
sv.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));                                                                                                   
sv.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: could you take a look at mine https://stackoverflow.com/q/45654166/7039895 I am stuck and I see you figured it out but I do not know how to apply it to my code.